# "dockerfile parse error line 1 from requires either one or three arguments" but I have only 1 argument

Tags: docker, dockerfile

tl;dr: Docker error as soon as I have more than 1 line in my `Dockerfile`.

- Dev environment: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS in WSL (Bash)
- Build environment: Windows Server 2019 (PowerShell)

---

Version 1 of my Dockerfile:

```
FROM hello-world:nanoserver-1809
```

Build command:

```
docker build -t hello-world:windows .
```

Output:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  4.096kB 
Step 1/1 : FROM hello-world:nanoserver-1809
 ---> bb8a46951ebd
Successfully built bb8a46951ebd
Successfully tagged hello-world:windows
```

--> This is OK!

---

Version 2 of my Dockerfile:

```
FROM hello-world:nanoserver-1809

WORKDIR tmp
ADD https://github.com/ArtifexSoftware/ghostpdl-downloads/releases/download/gs952/gs952w64.exe .
RUN gs952w64.exe /S
```

Build command:

```
docker build -t hello-world:windows .
```

Output:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  4.096kB 
Error response from daemon: Dockerfile parse error line 1: FROM requires either one or three arguments
```

--> This is unexpected!

---

Honestly, I'm baffled. What's wrong here? How do I write simple dockerfiles that don't produce unexpected errors?

Comment: Are there line-ending problems?  If one system is Linux and the other Windows, is there either a missing or extra carriage return character that's causing the end-of-line to be misinterpreted?

Comment: Have you tried using absolute path in workdir? instead of WORKDIR tmp you should have WORKDIR /tmp

Comment: That doesn't change anything, @EdcelCabreraVista. It's not even getting that far. It's still at the `FROM` line and it hasn't reached `WORKDIR` yet. So, @EdcelCabreraVista, I believe that you are on the wrong track.

Comment: @DavidMaze `file Dockerfile` tells me it's `ASCII text, with CR line terminators`.

Comment: Neither `dos2unix` nor `unix2dos` wanted to change the line endings. Finally I opened the file with `nano` and saved it as `DOS`. Now `file` says `ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators`, and `docker build` works! Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution found thanks to the comment of David Maze.

Turns out I had *Mac* line endings (CR), which is ridiculous, because I don't even own a Mac.

Neither `dos2unix` nor `unix2dos` wanted to fix the line ending problem. So in the end I opened the file in `nano`, and saved it with DOS (CRLF) line endings using Ctrl+O, Alt+D. With this, my `Dockerfile` worked.

Then I used `dos2unix` to convert the line endings from CRLF to LF, and that version also works.

To summarize:

- CR line terminators (Mac): doesn't work
- LF line terminators (Linux): works
- CRLF line terminators (DOS): works